# How to find pid of a process by Python?

Tags: python, pid

friends:

I am running a script in Linux:

I can use the `ps` command get the process.

```
ps -ef | grep "python test09.py&"
```

but, how can I know the pid of the running script by given key word `python test09.py&` using python code?

---

**EDIT-01**

I mean, I want to use the python script to find the running script `python test09.py&`'s pid.

---

**EDIT-02**

When I run anali's method I will get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 363, in catch_zombie
    yield
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 429, in cmdline
    return cext.proc_cmdline(self.pid)
ProcessLookupError: [Errno 3] No such process (originated from sysctl)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test11.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(get_pids_by_script_name('test09.py'))
  File "test11.py", line 15, in get_pids_by_script_name
    cmdline = proc.cmdline()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psutil/__init__.py", line 694, in cmdline
    return self._proc.cmdline()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 342, in wrapper
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 429, in cmdline
    return cext.proc_cmdline(self.pid)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 376, in catch_zombie
    raise AccessDenied(proc.pid, proc._name)
psutil.AccessDenied: psutil.AccessDenied (pid=1)
```

Comment: Please can you clarify what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to find out the pid inside the *same* python process (just use `os.getpid()`) or are you trying to find out the pid of *another* python process based on its command line? And if the second option, then is it always one of *your* processes, or could it be a process that is run by another user?

Comment: I want to find the pid of the running script. such as I can use `ps -ef | grep xxx`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want the pid of the *current* script, then use `os.getpid`:

```
import os
pid = os.getpid()
```

However, below is an example of using [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) to find the pids of python processes running a named python script.  This could include the current process, but the main use case is for examining *other* processes, because for the *current* process it is easier just to use `os.getpid` as shown above.

`sleep.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
time.sleep(100)
```

`get_pids.py`

```
import os
import psutil


def get_pids_by_script_name(script_name):

    pids = []
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():

        try:
            cmdline = proc.cmdline()
            pid = proc.pid
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            continue

        if (len(cmdline) >= 2
            and 'python' in cmdline[0]
            and os.path.basename(cmdline[1]) == script_name):

            pids.append(pid)

    return pids


print(get_pids_by_script_name('sleep.py'))
```

Running it:

```
$ chmod +x sleep.py

$ cp sleep.py other.py

$ ./sleep.py &
[3] 24936

$ ./sleep.py &
[4] 24937

$ ./other.py &
[5] 24938

$ python get_pids.py 
[24936, 24937]
```

Comment: Your way works. but should except more: `[psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied,]`

Comment: @244boy I am not convinced that trapping `psutil.AccessDenied` is necessary. It is only trying to read `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`, which is world-readable. It would be a different matter if trying to extract for example the environment variables (dependent on access to `/proc/<pid>/environ`) which are protected.

Comment: In general, I don't like trapping exceptions other than the ones which there is a reason to believe should occur, because doing so can hide bugs. The reason for trapping `psutil.NoSuchProcess` is just in case there is a process that terminates in the short time that it takes to iterate over them (and the parent process has `wait`ed for it, if indeed the parent proces still exists) .

Comment: I also see that another answer also traps `psutil.ZombieProcess`. I am not sure under what circumstances that exception could be raised, but I have tested that accessing `proc.pid` and `proc.cmdline()` for a zombie process does not raise any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and do a string matching against the cmd line

```
import psutil
# Iterate over all running process
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        # Get process name & pid & cmd line from process object.
        processName = proc.name()
        processID = proc.pid
        print(proc.cmdline())
        print(processName , ' ::: ', processID)
    except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Subprocess Library

```
import subprocess
script_name = "test09.py"
ps_out = subprocess.Popen("ps -ef".split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().decode('UTF-8').split("\n") # Launch command line and gather output
for entry in ps_out:  # Loop over returned lines of ps
    if script_name in entry:
        script_pid = entry.split()[1] # retrieve second entry in line
        break
print(script_pid)
```

Comment: True, the pipe symbol '|' is not accepted using subprocess. Use the for loop insead of grep command. @244boy