# How to get the process ID of python programm?

Tags: python, process

Is there a way to get the process ID (PID) of a python program?

The program was started from the command line.

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649125/obtaining-pid-of-a-shell-python-script-inside-the-script-itself

Comment: Or [How to find pid of a process by Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737969/how-to-find-pid-of-a-process-by-python)

Comment: @NateW you should click on `Flag` button underneath and then choose `Duplicate` and then paste in the link. This way the question gets moderation attention and can be closed or is automatically closed as duplicate. Just as a hint :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it:

```py
import os
pid = os.getpid()
print(pid)
```